# Keep Looping inside return new promise

Tags: javascript, mongoose, es6-promise

I got a problem when trying to create a Number Increment of letter number.
The problem is my function run 2 loops inside **return new promise (resolve,reject)** function.

here is my code:

```
noSurat = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            doc = await model.findOne({ month: monthNumber }, null, { sort: { no: -1 } })
            result = await CheckNumber(doc)
            console.log("this is result",result)
            resolve(result)
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err)
        }
    })
}
```

here is the output:

```
this is result
Object {no: "NO: 55/VI/MSC/TTC/TIMIKA/2020", id: "5ef2cf8f70f7e00018ba8948"}
this is result
Object {no: "NO: 56/VI/MSC/TTC/TIMIKA/2020", id: "5ef2cf8f70f7e00018ba8949"}
Email sent: 250 2.0.0 OK  1592971197 191sm17848375pfy.161 - gsmtp
```

Why it's happening? I think if promise find resolve it's done and does not iterate anymore

Comment: if you can share more codes, that would be helpful. are you expecting more iteration? or no iteration at all?

Comment: you need to check how many times this `noSurat` function is triggering

Comment: @user9879287 i expect no itteration just once. I guess the code is lit. other code just call functions

Comment: @Raj Kumar No Surat just Trigger Once

Comment: then i think issue is not because of promise, its somewhere triggering twice, check fiddle, which i do the same await format and its triggering only once. https://jsfiddle.net/tgokqyc0/

Comment: can you console.log(doc) and result

Comment: @user9879287 the result :

null: this is doc
null: model {$__: InternalCache, isNew: false, errors: undefined, $locals: Object, $op: null, …}
null: this is result
null: Object {no: "NO: 57/VI/MSC/TTC/TIMIKA/2020", id: "5ef2e334e5873b00195f7721"}
null: this is doc
null: model {$__: InternalCache, isNew: false, errors: undefined, $locals: Object, $op: null, …}
null: this is result
null: Object {no: "NO: 58/VI/MSC/TTC/TIMIKA/2020", id: "5ef2e334e5873b00195f7722"}

the function called twice so it return 2 results